# Jetpack Compose can't import constrainAs

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I can't import constrainAs in Jetpack Compose.

```
 Text("Text", Modifier.constrainAs(text) {
            top.linkTo(button.bottom, margin = 16.dp)
        })
```

I added constraintlayout dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-alpha08"
```

But it still says Unresolved reference: constrainAs

Answer (score 8):

`constrainAs` belongs to `ConstraintLayoutScope`

it means that in can be used for any view inside `ConstraintLayout`, but only on a first level child.

```
ConstraintLayout {
    val ref = createRef()
    Box(
        // OK
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(ref) {

        }
    ) {
        Box(
            // Not OK
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(ref) {

            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: How did I miss that! Thank you :)!

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the following import?

`androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ConstraintLayout`

You don't need to import `constraintsAs` separately.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use another version :

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-beta02"
```